# How do I create and Axis2 client

Tags: apache-axis, webservice-client

I've been given a WDSL file and have to create a web service client using axis2. I've been able to generate the CallbackHandler and Stub using WSDL2java. I've tried following this tutorial to create the Client http://briansjavablog.blogspot.com.au/2013/01/axis2-web-service-client-tutorial.html
I'm not sure if I implemented the client properly. It runs, but I'm not sure how you view any output results. I've never dealt with web services before. The Stub file that was generated contains so much code, how am I supposed to know what I should be calling? All tutorials I've found give example Clients, but I want to know what I need to look at to create my own.
If anyone has any advice or links to creating clients that are easy to understand, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this probably went un-answered for a while due to the fact that the question is not clear and you probably need an introduction to Web Services and SOAP in general.  If you are given the WSDL (or can pull it from a URL out there somewhere) then you are using the Web Service as a client - you have (from the post) already created the stub for client use.  You simply need to use it.  You are sending a request to the server (Web Service) and sending it the data that it requires (as the SOAP parameters that are laid out in the Web Service schema). Based on this SOAP request you will get a response.  Your stubs that are created for the client act as the invocation and response points for your client.

So your question as to how do you test it: you decide what to do with the response as this is what you are coding into the client.

And about creating your own Web Service - you would need to start with a schema (often times you write your objects/data and the functions that you want them to perform and tools (like Axis2) will generate the server code (for Web Services and SOAP transport) on top of this.

So in your question, I think that you need to a) check out some Web Services books/online tutorials to figure out what it is, b) code your client to display the results and stuff - and just make sure that you are actually sending and getting responses from the Web Service, and c) also see what it would take to create your own Web Service (for whatever purpose you are planning the service to be established for, before creating your own.

Effectively I think that you just need to get your feet wet with Web Services in the first place.  And the tutorial that you pointed out ( http://briansjavablog.blogspot.com.au/2013/01/axis2-web-service-client-tutorial.html) is excellent for anyone looking to get a web services client started - thanks for posting that.